# Programatically adding Taxonomy text field

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

This code is throwing a *FieldException: Attempt to create a field of unknown type text. in field_create_field() (line 111 of C:\wamp\www\local.test\modules\field\field.crud.inc).*

```
field_cache_clear();

//Create the appropriate field type
$field = array(
    'field_name' => 'stock_exchange',
    'type' => 'text',
    'module' => 'text',
    'active' => '1',
    'cardinality' => '1',
    'settings' => array( 
        'max_length' => 64 
    )
);
field_create_field($field);

$instance = array(
    'field_name' => 'stock_exchange',
    'entity_type' => __DEFAULT_VOCAB_MACHINE_NAME,
    'bundle' => __DEFAULT_VOCAB_MACHINE_NAME,
    'label' => 'stock_exchange',
    'description' => 'stock_exchange',
    'required' => false,
    'widget' => array(
        'type' => 'text_textfield'
    ),
);
```

At my wits end here trying to figure out why this won't work. Have tried clearing cache and it's not that.

For some reason it's not accepting a basic text field.

Any ideas?

Comment: At a guess, you have the Text module disabled

Comment: Appreciate the response @Clive. Text module is enabled: http://d.pr/i/osyb

Comment: That's mighty strange - what do you get as output for `field_info_field_types('text')`? It should be an array with 10 or so items representing the text field type. Sounds like that's missing; do you have any custom/contrib modules that might be implementing `hook_field_info_alter()` and doing something to displace the core text type?

Comment: @Clive My thoughts exactly. The output is **null**. 

Just checked all of the contrib modules I have and none of them use that hook. I can create all of the fields with _number_decimal_ as the type and it works. For some reason the text field has disappeared on me.

Comment: Wow. What about `module_invoke_all('field_info')`, does that contain the text field type?

Comment: @Clive oddly enough it does not

Comment: @Clive could this be a core bug?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve adding a text field to a Taxonomy Vocabulary is to place it in the *hook_enable()* function of your module.

If it's outside of that the "Text" module won't be loaded and you'll receive the error above.

**If anyone has a way around that please let me know.**

Comment: Appears to be related to this core issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/1239370